# Switch off LED touch light in app (Android phone)

Tags: android, led

In android phone, when I use my apps, after exiting it still shows the LED light of the touch buttons (Home/back/menu) (I did not set anything about that button light but only change the screen brightness in the program). Is there any way to permanently switch that light off? (Disable it). (HTC One X phone). Does my program interfere with power system?
Many thanks

Comment: Hi, is this a programming question?  If not, try http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes, i mean any way in programming of my apps to prevent the problem

Comment: The backlight behind the hard-buttons on the HTC I use are directly linked to the brightness of the screen. Unless you override the display's brightness, your app doesn't have control over this.

Comment: To permanently disable light... acquire soldering iron, solder sucker, and a few screw drivers, take the phone apart using screw drivers, find the LEDs that are behind these buttons, heat the solder up around them, use the solder sucker to remove solder, there you go, permanently disabled ;D haha. In all serious don't do this.

Comment: @Sam, I think that is the problem as I set the brightness and sometime the button backlight is on which then affect to my brighness setting.

Comment: @SmartLemon, I would not do that though it sounds straight forward, haha

Comment: It was more of a joke then anything else xD

Answer (score 0):

If you have to turn off these buttons led light in HTC ONE X, you need to press and hold power  and home button than after a few seconds those led lights will start blinking. After that release power button. Your button's led lights will turn off. JUST FOR HTC ONE X!